# Why is Json Dot Net not even trying to evaluate my interface properties?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an object where I'm trying to intercept the deserialization process for two properties which are interfaces.  I'm using Json Dot Net.

The issue that I'm facing is that Json Dot Net doesn't even try to convert the two IDataStore properties.  In other words, 'CanConvert' is never even run for those types.

I've tried adding JsonProperty and JsonConverter attributes and still no dice.

Any insight would be appreciated.

**Edit (and Answer)** *After being asked by Ron Beyer to post the JSON, it became clear that Json Dot Net doesn't even consider operating on a property if the source JSON doesn't have it.  When adding '"SourceDataStore":{}' it tries to convert that property.  I was thinking it would look at the current object type and iterate over that but there's obviously a matching process beforehand*

**JSON**

```
{
"Name":"My First Definition",
"SourceDataStoreType":"SqlDataStore",
"DestinationDataStoreType":"MongoDataStore"
}
```

**Class**

```
internal class Definition
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DataStoreTypes SourceDataStoreType { get; set; }

        public DataStoreTypes DestinationDataStoreType { get; set; }

        public IDataStore SourceDataStore { get; set; }

       public IDataStore DestinationDataStore { get; set; }

        public Definition()
        {

        }
    }
```

**Converter**

```
public class DataStoreConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            var b = objectType == typeof(IDataStore);

            return b;
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return new SqlDataStore();
        }

        public override bool CanWrite
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Code**

```
var definition = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Definition>(definitionsJson, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                Converters = new[] { new DataStoreConverter() }
            });

            return definition;
```

Comment: Can you post the associated JSON as well?

Comment: You answered it! indirectly at least.  Json.Net requires the json text to have data for the property.  I was thinking I could just boot up a new SqlDataStore()...but I need to have "SourceDataStore":{} for Json Dot Net to even consider it.  Thanks.

Comment: Thats what I was kind-of getting at, glad you resolved it. Without having the property name there, you won't get a request to deserialize it and it won't hit your converter. With the property in the JSON, and it being named properly, it should work. As far as how it does it, it iterates through the JSON and inspects the type for a matching property, not the other way around (match all properties to the JSON), so it doesn't even notice the property is missing.

Comment: Go ahead and enter that as an answer so I can close this out.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Comments to an answer)

I asked for the JSON example to verify that 1) the JSON was well formatted and 2) included the properties in question.

The issue, it turns out that you figured out, is that the JSON deserializer will not attempt to run the conversion on any properties it does not find in the JSON. This is because the deserializer parses the JSON and looks for appropriate properties in the object to fill in. If the property doesn't exist in the JSON, it won't attempt to build that property from nothing.

There are two solutions to this, either you can add a null (blank) property for those in the JSON, or you can edit your object to create them when you run the constructor, something like:

```
internal class Definition
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DataStoreTypes SourceDataStoreType { get; set; }

    public DataStoreTypes DestinationDataStoreType { get; set; }

    public IDataStore SourceDataStore { get; set; }

    public IDataStore DestinationDataStore { get; set; }

    public Definition()
    {
        var container = YourIOCContainerHere.Instance;
        SourceDataStore = container.Resolve<IDataStore>();
        DestinationDataStore = container.Resolve<IDataStore>();

        //Or, without using IOC/DI
        SourceDataStore = new SqlDataStore();
        DestinationDataStore = new SqlDataStore();
    }
}
```